# Is finding and loading jfxrt.jar programatically at start up a bad idea?

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a swing application that includes some JavaFX code. I'm fully aware of the issues around jfxrt.jar living in the lib rather than ext directory and not being available by default.

Give that:
 * I don't want to use the JavaFX Maven Plugin
 * I don't want to bundle a jre
 * I'm happy to programatically work around systems that don't have Java Fx available (I'm only using Java FX for a few graphs)

Are there any issues with running the following code at start up in my application? I've tested it on windows, mac and linux with a variety of jre's that do and don't have the Java FX jar bundled (OpenJDK/Oracle/Java7/Java6 combinations etc).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JavaFxJarLoader
{
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JavaFxJarLoader.class.getName());

private static final String JFXRT_JAR = "jfxrt.jar";
private static final String JRE_LIB_SUFFIX = File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "ext";

public static boolean javaFXAvailable()
{
    boolean wasFound = true;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("javafx.scene.chart.PieChart");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        wasFound = false;
    }
    return wasFound;
}

public static void tryToMakeJavaFXAvailable()
{
    if ( javaFXAvailable())
    {
        logger.info("Java FX availble by default, no action taken");
    }
    else
    {
        final File javaFxJarFile = findJavaFxJarFile();

        if ( javaFxJarFile != null )
        {
            try
            {
                addURLToSystemClassLoader(javaFxJarFile.toURI().toURL());
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                logger.warning(e.toString());
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("Failed to find " + JFXRT_JAR + ", Java Fx not available on this system.");
        }
    }
}

// Uses java.ext.dirs to find the jfxrt.jar file.
private static File findJavaFxJarFile()
{
    File ret = null;
    final String javaExtDirs = System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs");

    logger.info("Seraching for " + JFXRT_JAR + ", using java.ext.dirs = '" + javaExtDirs + "'");

    if ( javaExtDirs != null )
    {
        final String dirs[] = javaExtDirs.split(File.pathSeparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.length; i++)
        {
            final String dir = dirs[i];

            if ( dir.endsWith(JRE_LIB_SUFFIX))
            {
                final String jfxPath = dir.substring(0, dir.length()-3) + JFXRT_JAR;
                final File jfxFile = new File(jfxPath);

                final boolean selected = jfxFile.exists();
                logger.info("Candidate " + JFXRT_JAR + " in " + jfxFile.toString() + " " + (selected ? "will be used" : "ignored, does not exists"));
                if ( selected )
                {
                    ret = jfxFile;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

private static void addURLToSystemClassLoader(URL url) 
{ 
    final URLClassLoader systemClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(); 
    final Class<URLClassLoader> classLoaderClass = URLClassLoader.class; 

    try 
    { 
        final Method method = classLoaderClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class}); 
        method.setAccessible(true); 
        method.invoke(systemClassLoader, new Object[]{url});
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    { 
        logger.warning("Failed to add " + url.toString() + " to class path: "  + t.toString());
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    logger.warning("Java Fx available before ? " + javaFXAvailable());
    tryToMakeJavaFXAvailable();
    logger.warning("Java Fx available after ? " + javaFXAvailable());
}
}
```